# Is there a way to dequeue from a queue and enqueue to another queue?

Tags: c, pointers, queue

Hey all I've been working on a program using two queues. Where a stream of numbers enters one queue and is then dequeued from the first queue and enqueues to a second queue.

I've tried everything I can think of but nothing seems to work, I can't find anything online either.

Comment: Can you provide a MWE please, so we can see what you are trying to acheive?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages.  You need to show your best effort so we can help correct your problems.  We cannot guess what you're doing wrong if you don't show us the code.  The designs of the queue functions matters — there are many ways of writing the interfaces to the queuing functions, and you've shown us nothing.  That leads the sceptical people to think "they've got nothing; they just want us to write the code for them", often with justice.  Create an MCVE ([MCVE]) showing your best effort and we can help.  No code, no help.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with: `q1.push(q2.front()); q2.pop();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are queueing and dequeueing NODE structs containing the actual data, consider the following:

The dequeue function of your queue data structure should return the dequeued struct (or a pointer to it). By doing this you can simply write

```
NODE *node_dequeued_from_queue1 = Dequeue(&queue1);
Enqueue(&queue2, node_dequeued_from_queue1->data);
```

Where *dequeued_data* is a node struct containing a member data of type int.

Comment: It might be worth adding a check that there was a valid pointer.  Presumably, under this design, `Dequeue()` would return a NULL pointer if there is nothing in the queue to be dequeued. It's also quite possible that `Enqueue()` might be unhappy about being told to queue 'nothing'.  It might also return a status indicating success or failure.

Comment: I'll also observe that the question is difficult to answer because the person asking has shown no code.  In general, be cautious about answering such questions.  I think your answer is useful, but you've had to make too many assumptions for anyone's comfort (though I think you've mostly made reasonable assumptions — I'm not sure I would've expected the `->data` in the call to `Enqueue()`, but I can see how it might be OK).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the input, a check for null pointer would indeed be a very good idea here as well as a success / failure flag. And thank you for the pointer (pun intended) regarding answering posts without a MWE.